# Translating Ruby. How do I do this in Python?

Tags: python, ruby, code-translation

I want to find a particular element in a list like this:

```
my_list.find { |e| e == 'find this' }
```

I know in Python I can do:

```
[e for e in my_list if e == 'find this']
```

But this returns a list as opposed to the element I want.

I know how I can do this by iterating through the list, but I want to know if there's a more concise way of doing it.

Comment: You mean you want to find the *first matching element*?

Comment: In your simplified case, the result would be the same as `'find this' if 'find this' in my_list else None`, as you are using equality here.

Comment: Are you actually using `#find_index` ?

Comment: It's not necessary to say "Edit:" or notate that something changed. Stack Overflow keeps an edit history so we can see how things have changed if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the *first* matching element with a generator expression and `next()`:

```
match = next((e for e in my_list if e == 'find this'), None)
```

This sets `match` to `None` if no elements matched.

Because a generator expression is used, only enough elements in `my_list` are inspected to find the first match, after which the search is stopped.

The sample search you gave is rather pointless, of course, as you are basically using simple equality. For more complex attribute searches it makes more sense.

Comment: I suspect the OP meant `find_index` in which case @miku's answer is correct :)

Comment: @JonClements: maybe, maybe not. We'll see!

Comment: Mind you, have remembered depending on the Ruby version, there's the `Enumerable` interface so `.find` would correlate with this answer (using the default parameter to return `None` is similar to the `nil` result Ruby returns from `.find`) :p

Comment: Indeed, this is equal to [Ruby's Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find). It yields the first matching element or `nil`, not the index.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers: then `next()` with a generator expression and a default does exactly that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I was referring to your answer so we agree :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [list.index](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), which

> returns the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

```
>>> l = ["1", "se", "uz", "tz", "find this", "that"]
>>> l.index("find this") 
4

>>> l[l.index("find this")]
'find this'

>>> l[l.index("find that")]
...
ValueError: 'find that' is not in list
```

If all your app does is searching for *exact* keys, you could also use a dictionary (called [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html) in Ruby, I guess) instead - to reduce lookup times from O(n) to amortized O(1).

Comment: We just call it a hash in Ruby. It's called many things in different languages.

Comment: Just corrected it this moment, after skimming the Ruby docs, but thanks for noticing.